# jQuery update link

Tags: jquery, attributes

Here is html:

```
<a href="http://site.com/any/different/folders/picture_name.jpg">Go and win</a>
<a href="http://site.com/not/similar/links/some_other_name.png">Go and win</a>
```

How to add some text **after last `"/"` in `href`** attribute (before `picture_name.jpg`) of each link?

The script should give something like:

```
<a href="http://site.com/any/different/folders/user_picture_name.jpg">Go and win</a>
<a href="http://site.com/not/similar/links/user_some_other_name.png">Go and win</a>
```

Here `user_` is added.

Each link is `var img_link`

There can be any length of the link.

Comment: thats why we search for the last "/"

Comment: Scroll down a bit if you want a non regular expression version. ;o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice and clean. No splits, no arrays, no regular expressions. :o)

**Test it here:** http://jsfiddle.net/Pjdtm/

```
    var index = img_link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;

       // "result" now stores the new href. 
    var result = img_link.substr(0,index) + 'user_' + img_link.substr(index);
```

Comment: +1 for that awesome tool. Plus, I believe that this is the most efficient implementation. You might want to change your jQuery selection to `$('a[href]')`, to get rid of some weird edge cases.

Comment: @eagle - You mean jsFiddle? Yeah, it is awesome. :o)

Comment: @eagle - Didn't see your edit. Yeah, the selector is pretty generic. Not sure if this is more efficient (3 function calls), but is a little prettier than regex. With Happy's last comment under your answer, I'm not sure if we're on the right track at all.

Comment: please update - it should work with "img_link" variable, not to parse href of the link

Comment: @Happy - They're all in one variable? Are they in an array, or all in one string, or how are they stored?

Comment: @patrick: yeah I'm confused too, please let me know once you understand what OP wants, and I'll update my answer too.

Comment: @Happy - Could you please post the content of the variable and whatever other relevant information there is. Your question only made reference to HTML elements. If that is not the case, then you need to post the actual situation.

Comment: its used inside other .each, thats why I'm asking to use given variable

Comment: we should parse img_link like it is a href of one link

Comment: @eagle - The *issue* was that Happy was already  in an `each()`, and was using a the local variable `img_link` to store the href. Our answers were correct. Mine just needed a minor tweak to make it explicitly accurate. I don't see how you would need to change yours at all.

Answer (score 7):

This solution uses [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) which are excellent at simple string manipulation such as this:

```
$('a[href]').each(function() {
  var img_link = $(this).attr('href');
  $(this).attr('href', img_link.replace(/([^\/]+)$/, "user_$1"));
});
```

**Updated** to use `img_link` as requested by OP.

If you already have the `img_link` variable and your own `each()` loop, simply use the one line inside the function, i.e.:

```
  $(this).attr('href', img_link.replace(/([^\/]+)$/, "user_$1"));
```

Comment: nice, better answer than mine for sure

Comment: href already placed in "var img_link", can you add code for it?

Comment: @eagle - I'm sorry, you don't need to use .each for a[href], because everylink's href already placed in "var img_link". Please update

Comment: @eagle - +1 since your solution was already complete. I actually feel a little bad about this one. :(

Comment: @patrick: no worries, I like your solution too. We gave OP options, which is always good. Plus, you introduced me to jsfiddle! :D

Answer (score 3):

So I would think that the best solution would make use of splice and join.

jQuery Example

```
$("a").each(function(){
var arr = $(this).attr("href").split("/")
arr[arr.length-1] = "_user" + arr[arr.length-1];
$(this).attr("href",arr.join("/"));
});
```

Comment: Possible, but there are pure regex ways that are probably *a lot* faster (and shorter). This code is easier to understand, though.

Comment: I find a simple regex solution easier to understand, but that's probably just me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. Use the following regex on the href attribute:

```
(http://.+/(?=.+"))(.+)
```

This will match `http://site.com/not/similar/links/` and `folders/user_picture_name.jpg` separately. Then you can combine the two matches with the text appended in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the attribute by 

`var hrefText = jQuery('a').attr('href');`

you can then modify the hrefText as:

`hrefText = hrefText.substr(0,hrefText.lastIndexOf('/'))+'user_'+hrefText.substr(hrefText.lastIndexOf('/')),hrefText.length);
//do this in each statement`

and then set the attribute again.

`jQuery('a').attr(hrefText);`

Having said that if you have number of links you should not go for a javascript approach